# Scrollview + scaling images = doesn't scroll properly, why not?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, scrollview, scale

I have an image that I scale to the width of the phone/tablet. It is 224x1632. The imageview is within the scrollview, and I need to be able to scroll up and down on that image.

The issue is that the scrollview sets according to the image size (1632 in length) on create, but when the image scales/stretches it is 3x taller than the original. Now the scroll-view is too small to scroll the entire image.

Any way to make the scrollview fit the image?

Note: the image length will differ per phone, so I can't set it to a predetermined size.

XML Code:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:src="@drawable/tiles" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You set your ScrollView's height to wrap_content which means "be as big as my content." You also set your ImageView's height to fill_parent which means "be as big as my parent." Either one of these statements is enough to prevent scrolling. Your ImageView should be wrap_content and your ScrollView should be fill_parent.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will try shortly when I am home and let you know how this goes!

Comment: Still doesn't adjust. Let me clarify. The scrollview scrolls, but it doesn't adjust when the ImageView changes to something much taller in height. So the scrollview starts out scrolling an image 1632px in height but when that increases to 3000, it doesn't expand...

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't expand?" The whole point of a ScrollView is to *not* expand.

Comment: The "limits" of the scrollview doesn't expand. It only scrolls 1/3rd of the image...

Answer (score 0):

Try `scaleType="center"` instead of `"centerCrop"`